# Geofence is not active after using proguard

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard, android-geofence

I have been using proguard to obfuscate my code but after using proguard Geofence is not working. Before implementing proguard Geofence was working perfectly.

Help me to know what am I doing wrong. I followed this [link too](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Any Idea

My proguard.txt is as follow:

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt

-dontwarn com.androidquery.**
-dontwarn com.actionbarsherlock.**
-dontwarn com.facebook.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn com.stripe.android.**
-dontwarn org.mockito.**
-dontwarn sun.reflect.**
-dontwarn android.test.**
-dontwarn com.estimote.sdk.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-dontwarn twitter4j.**
-dontwarn com.yetistep.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.timessquare.**
-dontwarn com.viewpagerindicator.**
-dontwarn com.astuetz.pagerslidingtabstrip.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep class oauth.signpost.**{ *; }

-keepclassmembers class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock {
<init>(android.app.Activity, int);
}

-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }

-keep class org.apache.commons.collections4.** { *; }

-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
 protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
 public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
@com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @JorgeGil I don't remember if this solution got solved.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response.

Comment: @JorgeGil if you seem to solve the issue please post your answer here.